# How to pass below xml into DomParser

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have try to get data from  this(http://www.livescience.com/home/feed/health.xml) xml file.But always my app give blank page with nullpointerexception

How should I change below  code segment to get rid from that

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
        RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

        NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
        int clength = nchild.getLength();

        // Get the required elements from each Item
        for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {

            Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
            String theString = null;
            String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

            theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

            if (theString != null) {
                if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                    // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                    // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                    _item.setTitle(theString);
                }

                else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                    _item.setDescription(theString);

                    // Parse the html description to get the image url
                    String html = theString;
                    org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                            .parse(html);
                    Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                    _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                }

                else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                    // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                    // empty string
                    String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                            "");
                    _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                }

            }
        }

        // add item to the list
        _feed.addItem(_item);
    }
```

This problem contains my other codes if needed
[Rss Feeds reader gives blank screen for .xml link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000340/rss-feeds-reader-gives-blank-screen-for-xml-link)

Comment: Are you sure that URL actually contains XML.  When I go there, I get *The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.*

Comment: I need to get RSS feeds from this website (Health Related)http://www.livescience.com/health/

Comment: Have you tried http://www.livescience.com/home/feed/site.xml ?